# Make a Page Control like the iOS 7 Camera app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7, uipagecontrol

I was curious as to how you would make the custom page control that Apple has implemented in their camera app, with the text essentially acting as the page control and moving along with the swipe.

Are they using a UI Element that has the text fade into the background like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the text on the bottom ("Video", "Photo", "Square", ...) there's no stock component for doing it.

If I had to implement it I'd try with a `UICollectionView` with a flow Layout. You can easily play with alphas and 3D transforms to achieve the same effect.

As a reference you may want to look at the [WWDC 2012 talks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) about `UICollectionView`, in one of which (can't remember which one) they explain how to build a cover flow interface with using a flow layout.